# How to make a button display the value of a file/image? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, button, innerhtml

I have a button called f1 and I want it to display the value of the image that the user puts when they select an image. For example, when you select an image it'll display on the screen but I also want it to display on the button with proper width and height attributes, how would I do that? I've tried the document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = input.value; but that only displays the file path, not the actual image. I appreciate the help.

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(250)
                    .height(200);
     
    
            };
   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   const f1 = document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = input.value;

            
   
        }
    }
```

```css
#f1 {
  width:50px;
  height:40px;
 }
 #img {
  position:relative;
  left:275px;
  top:200px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Filter Image</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
 <input type='file' id="file" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
    <img id="img"/>
 <button id = "f1"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to navigate another page or doing something when clicking that image?

Comment: Yes, when a user clicks the button the filter should change on the image. I can do that myself though.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(50)
                    .height(50);
     
    
            };
   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Filter Image</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
 <input type='file' id="file" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
    
 <button id = "f1"><img id="img"/></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the img tag inside button

Comment: Thanks but I want it to display on the button and the screen, not just on the button.

Comment: you can add the button in a ```<a href ="your link "> <img  src= "your image path"></a>``` .